# Buildroot : VFP register arguments error while compiling rpi-userland

Tags: floating-point, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi, buildroot

First of all, I don't know if this belongs here, but I need your help fellow coders colleagues !
I am trying to build my own linux stripped system using buildroot using the provided Raspberry Pi config. Although, I am facing an issue, when the 'make all' procedure is reaching the stage it is supposed to build rpi-userland, a weird error occurs.

I have weird compiling errors telling me that LD encountered an error while linking because : the previously compiled object file uses VFP register arguments.
As far as I know, this error occurs because there's a softfp and a hardfp conflict, although, after looking at the build parameters, I cannot determine the source of the problem.

My host configuration is an i686 Ubuntu PC, my target, as exposed above is the famous Raspberry Pi, so obviously I'm doing cross-compiling.
Here's where stuff happens :

```
Building C object
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec306248226.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

/home/robbyos/buildroot-2013.05/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pipe
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -Os -o
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec306248226.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
/home/robbyos/buildroot-2013.05/output/build/rpi-userland-5e9a740a88a889dfc8a18bb1b00c17e5dd9d0108/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec306248226

/home/robbyos/buildroot-2013.05/output/host/usr/bin/cmake -E
cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec306248226.dir/link.txt
--verbose=1

/home/robbyos/buildroot-2013.05/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pipe
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -Os
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec306248226.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
cmTryCompileExec306248226 -rdynamic


/home/robbyos/buildroot-2013.05/output/host/usr/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/ld:
error: CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec306248226.dir/testCCompiler.c.o uses VFP
register arguments, cmTryCompileExec306248226 does not
```

As you can see the compiler and the linker are both using the "-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpi=vfp" flags, hence I don't understand why these errors.
I hope someone out there can help me with this !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Please report this problem to the Buildroot mailing list, including all the details needed to reproduce it: Buildroot version, Buildroot configuration, etc.